# Plugin UPLOADIFY não envia MP3

Tags: jquery-plugins

Pessoal uso o plugin `UPLOADIFY` para enviar arquivos, mas acabei de descobrir que ele não esta enviando quando o arquivo tem a extensão .MP3. Se eu dou um `var_dump($_FILES)` ele volta vazio para mim quando é um arquivo .MP3 se eu passo por exemplo um PDF o `var_dump($_FILES);` volta preenchido?

```
$(".upload").uploadify({
        'uploader': '/public/js/Uploadify2.1.4/uploadify.swf',
        'script': '/uploadArquivo',
        'cancelImg': '/public/js/Uploadify2.1.4/cancel.png',
        'fileExt': '*.pdf; *.mp3;*.wav',
        'multi': false,
        'auto': true,
        'width': 120,
        'hideButton': false,
        'buttonText': 'Procurar',
        'rollover': false,
        'sizeLimit': '10485760', //Limitado a 5mb por arquivo. Valores expressos em bytes
        'displayData': 'speed',
        'queueSizeLimit': 1,
        'uploadLimit': 1,
        'onUploadStart': function(file) {
            console.log('=>'+file);
        },
        'onComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
            if (response == "erro") {
                alert("Problemas no upload deste audio.");
            } else {
                $("#imgfoto1").attr("src", "<?php echo AUDIO  ?>");
                $("#arquivo").attr("value", response);
            }
        },
        'onError': function(a, b, c, d) {
            if (d.type === "File Size")
                alert("O arquivo " + c.name + " excede o tamanho máximo. \nO Limite é de " + Math.round(d.info / (1024 * 1024)) + "Mb");
            else
                alert("Erro!!! " + d.type + ": " + d.text);
        }
    });
```

Na rota uploadArquivo só tem um `var_dump($_FILES)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema na verdade não estava no Plugin e sim no limite do tamanho do arquivo. Aumentei a tamanho do arquivo de 3 para 20 megas e tudo certo.
Obrigado

Comment: Eu pensei nisto, mas geralmente o PHP emite uma mensagem de erro e trava o script... estranho... – Só uma nota, eu testei sim e comigo funcionou normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei qual versão você está usando, mas isto está errado na última versão (usando SWF):

```
    'uploader': '/public/js/Uploadify2.1.4/uploadify.swf',
    'script': '/uploadArquivo',
```

- `uploader:` deveria ser o caminho do arquivo PHP
- `'swf':` que deveria ter o caminho do swf

Note que o Uploadify está na versão *v3.2.1* e aparentemente você está usando a versão 2.1.4, recomendo que atualize.

Download da versão atual: http://www.uploadify.com/download/

> Uploadify™ (versão Flash) está na versão 3.2.1
>
> UploadiFive™ (versão HTML5 - pago) está na versão 1.1.2

Para liberar permissões aos arquivos mp3, edite o `uploadify.php`:

```
$fileTypes = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png', 'pdf', 'mp3'); //Adicione MP3 aqui
$fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$fileTypes)) {
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo '1';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid file type.';
}
```

Comment: Eu estou usando a versao 2.1.4 não tenho como altera-la pois o projeto é antigo so estou dando uma atualizada nele. Imagino que o arquivo uploadify.php é o arquivo de envio do arquivo. É ai que esta o meu problema se na primeira linha desta arquivo eu colocar um var_dump($_files) ele me retorna vazio quando o arquivo é mp3.

Comment: Difícil dar suporte para algo que está obsoleto. Provavelmente é algum problema com o `uploadify.swf`, tente fazer um backup do seu swf e coloca o swf da versão 3, abre uma janela privativa (sem cache) e testa o upload @JoaoNivaldo (fraca da gambiarra kkkkkkkkk)

Comment: amigo se eu migrar para a versão 3 como você sugeriu como ficaria o meu script atualizado para a nova versão? Tem alguma alteração baseado no script que postei no início da pergunta? Obrigado

Comment: Aonde você leu no meu comentário que eu disse pra vc migrar tudo? Eu disse só pra trocar o swf e não mexer nos códigos @JoaoNivaldo

Comment: amigo eu náo disse que você falou para eu migrartudo. Eu disse que você sugeriu. E este foi o seu texto "Note que o Uploadify está na versão v3.2.1 e aparentemente você está usando a versão 2.1.4, recomendo que atualize.". Só estou tentando seguir sua sugestão e contando com sua ajuda. Não precisa ficar exaltado. Me desculpe se entendi algo errado.

Comment: olha fiz a troca para a nova versão do Uploadify e o erro persiste. Coloquei um var_dump($_Files) na primeira linha do uploadify.php e me retorna vazio quando o arquivo é MP3, se for outro formato volta os dados corretamente. O Engraçado é que quando eu escolho o arquivo ele faz o gráfica de envio ate o 100% corretamente ai termina e retorna vazio para o PHP. Você poderia testar ai por gentileza para ver se o problema é so aqui. Muito Obrigado